# Does a session beer have to be below a specific ABV?

Tags: ale, abv

Does anyone know if a "session beer" has to be below a specific ABV to qualify as a session beer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like many beer terms, "session beer" is not rigorously defined.  Several groups have tried, though:

- The [Brewers Association (PDF)](http://www.brewersassociation.org/attachments/0000/5183/BA_2011_Beer_Style_Guidlines.pdf) called it 4.0-5.1% ABV
- [Beer Advocate](http://beeradvocate.com/articles/653/) calls it less than 5%
- [The Session Beer Project](http://sessionbeerproject.blogspot.com/) calls it 4.5%.

Really, though, if you call something a session beer, most people will understand that to mean something you could easily drink several of in a session (ie, lighter and more mild than a "big" beer).

Comment: 5%?   If I attempt a session on Courage Directors, (4.9%), it gets auto-terminated after 5-6 pints.  I would go with the Brewewrs Association figure - I can drink Doombar, (4.0%), all day, (mostly, anyway:).